# How to open/get the variable for Modis data (Level 2) with format .nc in python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I have problem to open/get the variable for modis data (level 2) with format `.nc` in python. Normally I use netCDF4 module to open/get the variable (`sst`, `chlo_a`, `lon`, `lat`) for level 3 modis data and it works.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

f = r"F:\WORK\L3_modis\input\A2016006.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc"    
fh = Dataset(f, mode='r')    
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]  
sst = fh.variables['sst'][:]
```

but the script doesn't work to level 2 modis data. Here is the script:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

r = "F:\\WORK\\L3_modis\\input\\A2012001062000.L2_LAC_OC.x.nc"
fh = Dataset(r, mode='r')
sst = fh.variables['chlo_a'][:] #trying to get chlo_a variable
```

The problem is that it can't found the variable for level 2 modis data (`chlo_a`, `sst`, etc...).

As i know when i try modis level 2 in hdf format it works. The chloropyhll-a variable called 'chlor_a'. Here is the script:

```
import pyhdf.SD import SD
f=SD('D:\\ORS\cilacap_pacitan_2013079\A2013079064500.L2_LAC_OC.x.hdf')
print f.datasets().keys()
['l2_flags', 'elat', 'clon', 'vcal_offset', 'msec', 'vcal_gain', 'chlor_a', 'year', 'elon', 'wavelength', 'tilt', 'cntl_pt_rows', 'latitude', 'slon', 'slat', 'Tau_r', 'day', 'F0', 'k_oz', 'longitude', 'cntl_pt_cols', 'clat', 'csol_z']
data=array(F.select('chlor_a').get()) #trying to get chlor_a variable
print data
```

Comment: Does ncdump show the variables? Note also that netcdf is not case sensitive but Python dictionaries are. Please look at `fh.variables.keys()` to check for capitalization issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer **@Christoph** , honestly i don't know how to use ncdump. I try to understand it from <http://www.ceda.ac.uk/static/media/uploads/ncas-reading-2015/python_read_data_exercises_solutions.pdf>. I have tried 'fh.variables.keys()' but it is still not yet working.

Comment: You use `ncdump -h <filename>` from your shell. It should list you all contained variables. What is the content of `fh.variables.keys()`? My point, in case I wasn't clear, is that your variable might be called `CHLO_A` or something like that, which is the same for netCDF but not for Python. Edit: Sorry, I notice you are on Windows. Maybe ncdump is not an option for you. But you might try any netCDF viewer that you have to check if the variable actually exists. Or just focus on the other part of my comment.